# If U is a subspace of V, and dim U = dim V, then does U = V?

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

In Pinter's *A Book of Abstract Algebra* (Ch. 28, D2), the reader is asked to prove that if U is a subspace of V, and dim U = dim V, then U = V. I'm puzzled by why this claim is true. More precisely, I'm puzzled why the following isn't a counterexample.

Let V be the set of integers with addition over the binary field <sub>2</sub>. Let U be the set of even integers with addition over the binary field <sub>2</sub>. Since U ⊂ V and U is closed with respect to vector addition and scalar multiplication, U is a subspace of V.

Now, {1} is a basis of V. Therefore, dim V = 1. And {2} is a basis of U. Therefore, dim U = 1. But U != V, since U ⊂ V. So, why doesn't this show that the claim is false? Is there something wrong with my example?

Comment: You say: "Let $V$ be the set of integers with addition over the $\mathbb{Z}_2$. Are you sure this is a vector space?

Comment: The statemente is true, whenever they are finite dimensional spaces.
For the infinte dimensional case, take $V=\ell_2$ (square summable real sequences) and $U={\rm span}\{e_{2k},\, k\in\Bbb N\}$ where $e_j$ is the sequence with 1 in the $j-th$ coordinate and zero in the others.

Comment: $V$ is not a vector space over $\mathbb F_2$. It does not satisfy the distributivity: $0\cdot n=(1+1)\cdot n\ne n+n$.

Comment: Thank you. Now I see what I was confused about.